# Sequilize query to find JSON in array is not working

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

The request I'm trying:

```
select * from user_roles where user_role_actions @> '[{"action": "/api/users","method": "GET","menu": "Manage users"}]'
```

The data in the database:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "user_role_id": 1,
            "user_role_name": "Admin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ",
            "user_role_actions": "[{action: '/api/users', method: 'GET', menu: 'Manage users'},{action: '/api/users', method: 'POST', menu: 'Add user'},{action: '/api/users/:id', method: 'GET', menu: 'View user'},{action: '/api/users/:id', method: 'PUT', menu: 'Update user'}]",
            "user_role_job_fields": "\"{'job_media','job_quote','job_invoice', 'job_client','created_by', 'job_status', 'job_source', 'job_job_template_name', 'job_job_template_data' }\"",
            "user_role_audit_logs": "\"{'job_quote','job_invoice', 'job_client','job_status'}\"",
            "createdAt": "2020-04-10T07:19:44.543Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-04-13T08:50:23.728Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

The query is successful but it does not return any result.
`Total query runtime: 10 ms. 0 rows retrieved.`

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: show a sequelize query

Comment: Is it serialized correctly? it seems like some sort of double JSON encoding?

Comment: Rephrase title
Format content

Comment: Did you get the result by executing this SQL query directly without using sequelize.js?

Comment: user_roles.findAll({
        where: {
          user_role_actions:{
             [Op.contains]:[{"action": "/api/users","method": "GET","menu": "Manage users"}]
          }
        },
        attributes: ['user_role_actions','user_role_name']
      }).then(data => {
      res.status(200).send({
        data: data
      });
    })

Comment: @slideshowp2 no this is query : user_roles.findAll({ where: { user_role_actions:{ [Op.contains]:[{"action": "/api/users","method": "GET","menu": "Manage users"}] } }, attributes: ['user_role_actions','user_role_name'] }).then(data => { res.status(200).send({ data: data }); })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MY JSON is not right.
there are some JSON example
Ex for  a JSON array
Ex. ["one", "two", "three"]

Ex for a JSON object
Ex. { "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3 }
```